# Mocha/ExpectJs: Trying to implement revealing prototype module but unable to test

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I've read about the revealing prototype pattern. I've created a function that returns an object.

```
'use strict'

exports.testPrototype = (function() {
    function testMe() {
        return true
    }

    return {
        testMe: testMe
    }
})()

console.log(exports.testPrototype.testMe())

const test = Object.create(exports.testPrototype)
console.log(test.testMe())
```

The output of `console.log` is `true` on both calls.

The trouble is, I can't get Mocha to test it.

Here is my test:

```
const expect = require('expect')
const testPrototype = require('../testPrototype.js')

describe('testPrototype',() => {
    it('Should return true', ()=> {
        const test = Object.create(testPrototype)
        expect(test.testMe()).toEqual(true)
    })
})
```

When I run the test, I get the following error:

```
1) testPrototype Should return true:
     TypeError: testPrototype.testMe is not a function
      at Context.<anonymous> (testPrototype.spec.js:7:24)
```

I've been struggling with this all day. Why isn't the test working? Have I missed something simple?

Answer (score 0):

Your module is adding a property called `testProperty` to the exports object:

```
exports.testPrototype = ...
```

But the Mocha test file is using the exports object itself, and not that particular property:

```
const testPrototype = require('../testPrototype.js')
```

Instead, you need to explicitly use the property:

```
const testPrototype = require('../testPrototype.js').testPrototype
```